# Oracle SQL beginner, I need to join a few columns from 2 tables and use a count for a total result

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle SQL:
I have data from 2 tables listed here, these are examples as there are many rows for each table.
table Instructor:

| INSTRUCTOR_ID | SALUTATION | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | STREET_ADDRESS | ZIP | PHONE | CREATED_BY | CREATED_DATE | MODIFIED_BY | MODIFIED_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Mr | Fernand | Hanks | 100 East 87th | 10015 | 2125551212 | ESILVEST | 01/02/1999 | ESILVEST | 01/02/1999 |
| 102 | Mr | Tom | Wojick | 518 West 120th | 10025 | 2125551212 | ESILVEST | 01/02/1999 | ESILVEST | 01/02/1999 |
| 103 | Ms | Nina | Schorin | 210 West 101st | 10025 | 2125551212 | ESILVEST | 01/02/1999 | ESILVEST | 01/02/1999 |
| 104 | Mr | Gary | Pertez | 34 Sixth Ave | 10035 | 2125551212 | ESILVEST | 01/02/1999 | ESILVEST | 01/02/1999 |

Also, table for section:

| SECTION_ID | COURSE_NO | SECTION_NO | START_DATE_TIME | LOCATION | INSTRUCTOR_ID | CAPACITY | CREATED_BY | CREATED_DATE | MODIFIED_BY | MODIFIED_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 79 | 350 | 3 | 04/14/1999 | L509 | 107 | 25 | CBRENNAN | 01/02/1999 | CBRENNAN | 01/02/1999 |
| 80 | 10 | 2 | 04/24/1999 | L214 | 102 | 15 | CBRENNAN | 01/02/1999 | CBRENNAN | 01/02/1999 |
| 81 | 20 | 2 | 07/24/1999 | L210 | 103 | 15 | CBRENNAN | 01/02/1999 | CBRENNAN | 01/02/1999 |
| 82 | 20 | 4 | 05/03/1999 | L214 | 104 | 15 | CBRENNAN | 01/02/1999 | CBRENNAN | 01/02/1999 |

I am trying to get results from both tables:
first_name, last, name and I need to get the total number of sections in descending order for the total number of sections that each instructor teaches. I am confused. Please be gentle, I am a beginner with SQL!

So far I have tried several instances over the past hour to hour and a half. I am obviously making this harder than it really is. This is the last syntax I tried:

```
SELECT I.INSTRUCTOR_ID, 
    I.FIRST_NAME,
    I.LAST_NAME
    COUNT(S.SECTION_NO)
FROM INSTRUCTOR I
JOIN SECTION S 
on I.INSTRUCTOR_ID = S.INSTRUCTOR_ID
ORDER BY NUM_SECTIONS;
```

Answer (score 2):

Query you posted looks OK, but is missing a few things:

- a comma (after `last_name`)
- alias for the `count` function (as you're trying to sort data by it)
- `group by` clause because all non-aggregated function must be contained in that clause
- `desc` (as you said you want to sort result in descending order)

So:

```
  SELECT i.instructor_id,
         i.first_name,
         i.last_name,
         COUNT (s.section_no) num_sections
    FROM instructor i JOIN section s ON i.instructor_id = s.instructor_id
GROUP BY i.instructor_id, i.first_name, i.last_name
ORDER BY num_sections DESC;
```

Comment: This is a good answer. @lexytaylormb, please also note how the query gets more readable by having keywords in upper case and names in lower case. If you want to consider instructors without sections in your result, change the `[INNER] JOIN` to a `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`. As to the `GROUP BY` clause: The idea is that you want to get one result row per instructor, so you group by instructor_id. This is not sufficient in Oracle, though. This DBMS requires to also put first and last name either into the `GROUP BY` clause or apply some dummy aggregation (like `MAX`) on them.